# StringBuffer going to append path for every method call

Tags: java, stringbuffer, contextpath

i am setting contextPath dynamically by using StringBuffer in java file. Here for every call the path is appending to StringBuffer Object based on number of calls. How can i run below code properly.

```
StringBuffer blankDeposit = new StringBuffer();
                blankDeposit.setLength(0);
                String rcp = request.getContextPath();
                String create = "Create";
                blankDeposit.append("<a href="+rcp+"/deposit/showBlankDepositSheet.do>"+create+"</a>"+"a blank Deposit Sheet.");

                ActionHelper.formatInfoMessage(
                    mapping,
                    request,blankDeposit.toString());
```

Here `blankDeposit` should have the contextPath(/myapp)with the String. But i am getting a blank space instead of this. How can i do for this.

And the `blankDeposit` is appending the string by number of times i run. if i call five times then the above variable blankDeposit containing five times the appended string.

Comment: Does setLength set the maximum length?  What if you remove that line?

Comment: No. It sets minimum length to String Buffer. or to clear the buffer.

Comment: First check `request.getContextPath();` is null or not. Also it should not append five time as u said. Check the initialization part, whether in comes under perform/execute method.

Comment: No. I am not getting null value. it is retreiving contextPath as `/myapp` correctly. But the String is not showing in the page.

Comment: Add sysout to confirm your `rcp` is correct one.

Comment: You want this as output `<a href=/myapp/deposit/showBlankDepositSheet.do>Create</a>a blank Deposit Sheet.`?

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected. Check the contextPath. if that's fine, check any other code block works on `blankDeposit`.

```
StringBuffer blankDeposit = new StringBuffer();
blankDeposit.setLength(0);
String rcp = "/myapp";
String create = "Create";
blankDeposit.append("<a href="+rcp+"/deposit/showBlankDepositSheet.do>"+create+"</a>"+"a blank Deposit Sheet.");
System.out.println(blankDeposit.toString());
```

Output:

```
<a href=/myapp/deposit/showBlankDepositSheet.do>Create</a>a blank Deposit Sheet.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want contextPath as a dynamically. not as a static one. That's why i am using `request.getContextPath()`. your code goes to static.

Comment: I just gave an example, it doesn't need to be static. You could use `contextPath` itself, it should work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. But my requirement is to be dynamic contextPath.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer. Here i am passing parameter to the function

```
ActionHelper.formatInfoMessage(mapping, request,blankDeposit.toString());
```

But instead of that blankDeposit.toString() i am taking as

```
String rcp = request.getContextPath();
```

then i am sending this string as an argument to formatInfoMessage method.

```
ActionHelper.formatInfoMessage(mapping,request,"create.a.blank.deposit.sheet",rcp);
```

this rcp variable setting to Application.properties file. there it is set as

```
info.create.deposit.sheet=<a href="{0}/deposit/showBlankSheet.do">Create</a> a blank Sheet.
```